# Split string to list of object

Tags: c#, string, split

I have inputs like following:

```
"10+18+12+13" 
"10+18-12+13" 
"2-5"
```

e.g. number followed by a `"+"` or `"-"` 
I created class `MathOper`

```
public class MathOper
{ 
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string Oper { get; set; } //this display the number will be operated.
}
```

I want to return list of MathOper as following
`"10+18-12+13"` will return

```
new MathOper(){Num=10,"+"}
new MathOper(){Num=18,"+"}
new MathOper(){Num=12,"-"}
new MathOper(){Num=13,"+"}
```

I tried to code that by this way:

```
public class MathOperCreator
{
    private readonly string _mathString;//8+2-3
    public MathOperCreator(string mathString)
    {
        this._mathString = mathString.Trim();
    }
    public List<MathOper> Create()
    {
        var lMo = new List<MathOper>();
        int l = this._mathString.Length;//5
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i = i + 2)
        {
            char n = _mathString[i];
            int n1 = int.Parse(n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
            string o1 = "+";
            if (i > 0)
            {
                o1 = _mathString[i - 1].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            var mo = new MathOper { Num = n1, Oper = o1 };
            lMo.Add(mo);
        }
        return lMo;
    }
}
```

I found that it is only for number with one char, if the number is two char ,such as 18 , it doesn't work. 
Please advice how implement described functionality?

Comment: You should instead try [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) or some other existing expression parser... Or if you are trying to write one yourself start with separating string into tokens (like sequence of digits as single token)...

Answer (score 2):

This is a tested Solution

```
//Model class
public class MathOperation
{
    public Int32 Num { get; set; }
    public String Operation { get; set; }
}

   String testData = "10+18+12-13";
   String[] GetNumbers = testData.Split(new Char[] { '+', '-' });
   String[] GetOperators = Regex.Split(testData, "[0-9]+");

   //remove empty entries in operator
   GetOperators = GetOperators.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

   List<MathOperation> list = new List<MathOperation>();
   MathOperation mathOperation = new MathOperation();
    for (int i = 0; i < GetNumbers.Count(); i++)
{
       mathOperation.Num = Convert.ToInt32(GetNumbers[i]);               
       mathOperation.Operation = (i>GetOperators.Length)? GetOperators[i] : null;
       list.Add(mathOperation);
}
```

This will give a list like

```
{Num=10,"+"}
{Num=18,"+"}
{Num=12,"-"}
{Num=13,"null"} //as in my test string there is no char after 13
```

if you dont want a null always a + then

```
mathOperation.Operation = (i>GetOperators.Length)? GetOperators[i] : "+";
```

then This will give a list like

```
{Num=10,"+"}
{Num=18,"+"}
{Num=12,"-"}
{Num=13,"+"} //as in my test string there is no char after 13
```

Comment: According to question your output list is incorrect as it should create a list with following objects `{ (10, '+'), (18, '+'), (12, '-'), (13, '+')` for this string `10+18-12+13`

Comment: @Tafari modifies the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it works the way you wanted: (Easy to understand solution but not optimal)

```
public class MathOper
    {
        public int Num { get; set; }
        public string Oper { get; set; } //this display the number will be operated.
    }

    public class MathOperCreator
    {
        public readonly string _mathString;//8+2-3

        public MathOperCreator(string mathString)
        {
            this._mathString = mathString.Trim();
        }
        public List<MathOper> Create()
        {
            var lMo = new List<MathOper>();
            int l = this._mathString.Length;//5
            string _mathStringTemp;

            char[] charArr = _mathString.ToCharArray();

            if (charArr[0] != '+' || charArr[0] != '-')
            {
                _mathStringTemp = "+"+_mathString;
            }               else
            {
                _mathStringTemp = _mathString;
            }

            char[] delimitersNumb = new char[] { '+', '-' };
            string[] numbers = _mathStringTemp.Split(delimitersNumb,
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


            string[] operators = new string[numbers.Length];
            int count = 0;

            foreach (char c in _mathStringTemp)
            {
                if (c == '+' || c == '-')
                {
                    operators[count] = c.ToString();            
                    count++;
                }
            }

            for(int i=0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {

                lMo.Add(new MathOper(){Num = int.Parse(numbers[i]), Oper = operators[i]});
                Console.WriteLine(operators[i]+" "+numbers[i]);
            }

            return lMo;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
        //you can change in to MathOper
        List<Tuple<int, char>> result = new List<Tuple<int, char>>(); 
        string _mathString = "2-2+10-13"; //Test
        char sign = '-';
        if (_mathString[0] != '-') //checking the first sign
        {
            sign = '+';
        }
        while (_mathString.Length > 0)
        {
            int nextPl = _mathString.IndexOf('+');
            int nextMn = _mathString.IndexOf('-');

            if (nextPl == -1 && nextMn == -1) //condition when _mathString contains only number
            {
                result.Add(new Tuple<int, char>(int.Parse(_mathString), sign));
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //getting the end position of first number
                int end = nextPl == -1 ? nextMn : (nextMn == -1 ? nextPl : (Math.Min(nextPl, nextMn)));

                //retrieving first number
                result.Add(new Tuple<int, char>(int.Parse(_mathString.Substring(0, end)), sign));
                _mathString = _mathString.Remove(0, end);

                //retrieving next sign
                sign = _mathString[0];
                _mathString = _mathString.Remove(0, 1);
            }
        }
```